# Vercel not registering html, css, js files from a repository

Tags: git, github, deployment, vercel

I am trying to deploy a website on vercel. Link to the repository: https://github.com/Adam-Simon1/Price-Saver.
Its my first 'bigger' project i am working on. Its far from finished, but i just want to try deploying it. I have never used vercel or any service like that so appreciate any help given.

The problem is its returning error 404, since the path is probably wrong. I specified the path to the root directory as 'src', since it includes all the necessary files. I also tried specifying the folders inside the 'src' folder, although it still didn't work.

So thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Your deployment has failed, that's why you're getting a 404. You can see why at - https://vercel.com/adam-simon1/price-savvy/8P4nyC7frL5Srqc1LCC4Maz1GLRQ.

Comment: @Confuseious I redeployed it. And its active now, but still shows the error and doesn't display the files.

Comment: If the link is correct, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong to me. You may need to contact Vercel at vercel.com/help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will try to contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured out the reason. It was directory structure that was incorrect.
In my first one i had the index.html inside the html folder, but it has to be outside the folder.